# How to reference a var node in a script (per instance)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reference, instance, godot4

Am moving from Unity to Godot. There, you can put in the inspector the public variable and change it per instance, but I don't know how to do this in Godot.

I tried using public Node/Node3D and selecting in Godot's inspector, but it didn't even appear. Apparently (correct me if am wrong), you need to use onready vars or something like that (I still don't understand it), but that way you will only be able to reference the same node (gameObject) in all instances of the script, instead of a different one per instance.

Answer (score 0):

To export variable to the inspector from C# in Godot, you need to add the `[Export]` attribute to them.

You should be able to do that with your `Node` variable:

```
using Godot;

public partial class ExportExample : Node3D
{
    [Export]
    Node3D node;
}
```

See [C# exported properties](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/c_sharp/c_sharp_exports.html).

Comment: I tried both [Export] public Node3D[] bases { get; set; } and the same, but without the getters/setters reading the documentation... it doesn't work

Comment: @Feref28 Are you getting errors or warnings building the C# project? I do not know if there is any issue because it being a .NET array and not a Godot array.

Comment: Am not getting errors. I also tried [Export] public Godot.Collections.Array<Node3D> bases { get; set; }